# PostgreSQL/PostGIS Stack builder missing dlls (GeoDjango)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geospatial, geodjango

I've installed GeoDjango Spatial Database libraries using Enterprise DB Stack for Postgres 10 and it includes following packages. I am using Windows 10 OS and needed to setup GeoDjango. Please assist

```
PostGIS 2.4.3 bundle includes 
PostGIS 2.4.3 w 
GDAL 2.2.3, 
GEOS 3.6.2, Proj 4.9.3, 
pgRouting 2.5.2, 
osm2pgrouting 2.3.3, 
ogr_fdw 1.0.5
```

But now on Python I get this error below and I tried many posted answers but couldn't make it work. Quick hint will be great help.

Below is the error:

```
(gigfinder) C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\gigfinder>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\aggregates.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import ExtentField
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .collections import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\collections.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import (
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import gdal
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\dell\gigfinder\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 48, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Have you walked through Django documentation regarding following
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#modify-windows-environment

Comment: Already did it 8 times now by keeping track of each step. Also its more non-Window OS friendly.